Open Ended Problem: Estimating Productivity in a Factory
This is  a statistical problem I am working on and I would like to request some guidance from the respected community.

Suppose there is a factory that receives food orders.
The food sits in a warehouse and is then shipped
Employees process the orders on a first in, first out basis

Each week, I know (i.e. historical data) :

The total number of employees that showed up to work that week
How many food orders were processed at the end of that week
How many new food orders were received by the end of that week
How many food orders are currently backlog at the end of that week
Historically speaking, I assume that new intake is independent of new food orders and  existing backlog
Historically speaking, I assume that fluctuations (e.g. factory accidents, vacation, retirement) in the total number of employees each week is independent  of new food orders and existing backlogs

I know that it costs $x$ dollars to hire a new employee for 6 months. Suppose I hire one new employee - I want to estimate what would the (marginal) cost-benefit impact of hiring this new employee  on production and backlog.
I thought of two ways to work on this problem. I have studied basic regression models, but in this question it seems that the predictor variable itself was the response variable in a previous model. Statistically speaking, I am not sure if this is permissible.
Approach 1: Analyzing Net Benefit Directly

Define variables:
$$
   \begin{align*}
   t &: \text{time (in weeks)} \\
   E_t &: \text{number of employees at time t} \\
   \hat{P}_t &: \text{estimated number of orders processed at time t} \\
   \hat{R}_t &: \text{estimated number of orders received at time t} \\
   \hat{B}_t &: \text{estimated backlog at time t} \\
   x &: \text{cost to hire a new person}
   \end{align*}
   $$

Model the relationship between employees and processed orders:
$$\hat{P}_t = \hat{\alpha} E_t + \hat{\epsilon}_t$$
Where $\hat{\alpha}$ is the estimated average number of orders processed per employee per week, and $\hat{\epsilon}_t$ is the estimated error term.

Model the backlog:
$$\hat{B}_t = \hat{B}_{t-1} + \hat{R}_t - \hat{P}_t$$

Forecast orders received:
We can use time series forecasting methods like ARIMA to predict future orders:
$$\hat{R}_t = \hat{f}(\hat{R}_{t-1}, \hat{R}_{t-2}, ...) + \hat{\eta}_t$$
Where $\hat{f}$ is the estimated forecasting function and $\hat{\eta}_t$ is the estimated forecast error.

Estimate the impact of hiring a new person:
$$\Delta \hat{P}_t = \hat{\alpha}$$
$$\Delta \hat{B}_t = -\hat{\alpha}$$

Cost-benefit analysis:
$$\text{Cost} = x$$
$$\hat{\text{Benefit}} = \sum_{t=1}^{26} (\Delta \hat{P}_t \cdot \hat{v} - \Delta \hat{B}_t \cdot \hat{c})$$
Where $\hat{v}$ is the estimated value of processing an additional order and $\hat{c}$ is the estimated cost of holding an order in backlog.

Net benefit over 6 months (26 weeks):
$$\hat{\text{Net Benefit}} = \hat{\text{Benefit}} - \text{Cost}$$


From here, you can play around and try increasing more employees, and see what the estimated impact is. You can also try to create adverse scenarios where you artificially elevate the number of new food orders to put strain on the system (sensitivity testing)
Approach 2: Analyzing Net Benefit from Regression Coefficients
Model for New Orders:
$$\text{new orders}_t = c + \sum{i=1}^p \phi_i \cdot \text{new orders}_{t-i} + \sum{j=1}^q \theta_j \epsilon_{t-j} + \epsilon_t$$
Where:

$c$ is a constant term
$\phi_i$ are the autoregressive parameters
$\theta_j$ are the moving average parameters
$\epsilon_t$ is the error term

Model for Backlog:
$$\text{backlog}_t = f(\text{employees}_{t-1}, \text{backlog}_{t-1}, \text{new orders}_{t-1})$$
$$\text{backlog}_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot \text{employees}_{t-1} + \beta_2 \cdot \text{backlog}_{t-1} + \beta_3 \cdot \text{neworders}_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$$
Oras an ARIMAX model:
$$\text{backlog}_t = \beta_0 + \sum{i=1}^p \phi_i \cdot \text{backlog}_{t-i} + \beta_1 \cdot \text{employees}_{t-1} + \beta_2 \cdot \text{neworders}_{t-1} + \sum{j=1}^q \theta_j \epsilon_{t-j} + \epsilon_t$$
Where:

$\beta_0$ is the intercept
$\phi_i$ are autoregressive parameters for backlog
$\beta_1, \beta_2$ are coefficients for exogenous variables
$\theta_j$ are moving average parameters
$\epsilon_t$ is the error term

First fit both models using historical data to estimate all parameters.
For forecasting, project future employee numbers (controllable variable)
and use the new orders model to forecast future orders.
Forecast the backlog iteratively:
$$\hat{\text{backlog}}_t = \hat{\beta}0 + \sum{i=1}^p \hat{\phi}i \cdot \text{backlog}_{t-i} + \hat{\beta}1 \cdot \text{employees}_{t-1} + \hat{\beta}2 \cdot \hat{\text{neworders}}_{t-1} + \sum{j=1}^q \hat{\theta}j \hat{\epsilon}_{t-j}$$
From here, you can see the marginal impact of adding a new employee on reduction in backlog (i.e. the estimated regression coefficient). Note that this will not be causal, but rather associative.
Conclusion: Can someone help me understand if these statistically valid/legitimate modelling strategies -  or is not how statistical modelling is done? Can the predictor variable itself was the response variable in a previous model. Statistically speaking, I am not sure if this is permissible (i.e. big error propagation, impossible to calculate variance, etc.). Is there a better way to model this?

some ideas: VAR model approach (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression), Simultaneous Equations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_equations_model)?

I tried to simplfy the modeling procedure. Hope it is helpful!
First you need to construct two data-driven service and demand predictors $f_S$ and $f_D$ based on the following system:
$$B_t=  B_{t-1}+ D_t -f_S(E_t, B_{t-1}+ D_t),  t\in T$$
$$D_t=f_D(D_{t-1},\dots,D_{0}, t), t\in T$$
where $B_t$ is the backlog amount at time period $t$, $D_t$ is demand volum at time period $t$, and $E_t$ is the number of employees at time period $t$. In the phase of discovering predictors $f_S$ and $f_D$, you need to use historical data available for variables $D_t, B_t, E_t$.
Then, you can compute the profit of hiring a new employee as follows:
$$C_B\sum_{t\in T'}(b_t -b^+_t)-C_E$$
where
$$b_t=  b_{t-1}+ d_t -f_S(e_t, b_{t-1}+d_t),  t\in T',$$
$$b^+_t=  b^+_{t-1}+ d_t -f_S(e_t\color{blue}{+1}, b^+_{t-1}+d_t),  t\in T',$$
and where $T'$ denotes the set of target periods (26 weeks), $C_B$ is the weekly cost of backlog per order, $C_E$ is the total cost of hiring a new employee over the periods in $T'$, $e_t,t\in T'$ are control variables that should be determined by HR department, $d_t,t\in T'$ are estimates of demands (using the demand predictor), and $b_t,t\in T'$ and $b^+_t,t\in T'$ are estimates of backlogs before and after adding a new employee (based on the service predictor and other inputs).

@ Amir! thank you for this! would you use time series regression for this?

@farrow90  You are welcome! Using times series covering trends and seasonality is a rational choice for constructing the demand predictor, but you may also try other machine learning methods if they are not good enough. For the service predictor, you may start with a simple linear regression, but it may depend on the scale of demand or seasonal effects.

Can you please check out these if you have time? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4955824/difficulty-understanding-matrix-notation

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4956278/help-expanding-matrix-equations

Thank you so much!

@farrow90 I just answered your first question and provided useful links to continue.
