Difficulty understanding matrix notation in vector autoregression
I have the 3 following individual equations representing Time Series Models:
$$Z_t = \phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$$
$$X_t = \alpha_1 X_{t-1} + \beta_1 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_1 Z_{t-1} + \epsilon_{1t}$$
$$Y_t = \alpha_2 X_{t-1} + \beta_2 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_2 Z_{t-1} + \epsilon_{2t}$$
Here:

Z only depends on previous values of Z
X depends on previous values of Z, X, Y
Y depends on previous values of Z, X, Y

I want to try and write this is a VAR model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression). Here is my attempt in matrix form:
$$\begin{bmatrix} X_t \ Y_t \ Z_t \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \ c_2 \ c_3 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \ 0 & 0 & a_{33} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} X_{t-1} \ Y_{t-1} \ Z_{t-1} \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} \epsilon_{1t} \ \epsilon_{2t} \ \epsilon_{3t} \end{bmatrix}$$
Here is my question:
If I expand the VAR model, I get the 3 following equations:
$$X_t = c_1 + a_{11}X_{t-1} + a_{12}Y_{t-1} + a_{13}Z_{t-1} + \epsilon_{1t}$$
$$Y_t = c_2 + a_{21}X_{t-1} + a_{22}Y_{t-1} + a_{23}Z_{t-1} + \epsilon_{2t}$$
$$Z_t = c_3 + a_{33}Z_{t-1} + \epsilon_{3t}$$
I am unable to understand how the VAR model is fundamentally different compared to writing the 3 individual equations from above. The VAR model and the individual model both have the same structure and seem equivalent.
What exactly is different?

Are the parameters estimated differently? E.g.

$$L(\mathbf{c}, \mathbf{A}, \Sigma | \mathbf{X}) = \prod_{t=1}^T \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}|\Sigma|^{1/2}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{X}t - \mathbf{c} - \mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}{t-1})'\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{X}t - \mathbf{c} - \mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}{t-1})\right)$$
$$\mathbf{c} = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \ c_2 \ c_3 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \
0 & 0 & a_{33}
\end{bmatrix}$$
vs
$$L(\phi, \theta, \sigma_Z^2 | Z) = \prod_{t=1}^T \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_Z^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(Z_t - \phi Z_{t-1} - \theta \epsilon_{t-1})^2}{2\sigma_Z^2}\right)$$
$$L(\alpha_1, \beta_1, \gamma_1, \sigma_X^2 | X, Y, Z) = \prod_{t=1}^T \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_X^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(X_t - \alpha_1 X_{t-1} - \beta_1 Y_{t-1} - \gamma_1 Z_{t-1})^2}{2\sigma_X^2}\right)$$
$$L(\alpha_2, \beta_2, \gamma_2, \sigma_Y^2 | X, Y, Z) = \prod_{t=1}^T \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_Y^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(Y_t - \alpha_2 X_{t-1} - \beta_2 Y_{t-1} - \gamma_2 Z_{t-1})^2}{2\sigma_Y^2}\right)$$

Do the parameters share a common distribution (e.g. errors are now correlated and have a variance-covariance matrix)?, E.g.

$$\begin{bmatrix} \epsilon_{1t} \ \epsilon_{2t} \ \epsilon_{3t} \end{bmatrix} \sim N(0, \Sigma)$$
$$\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_X^2 & \sigma_{XY} & \sigma_{XZ} \
\sigma_{XY} & \sigma_Y^2 & \sigma_{YZ} \
\sigma_{XZ} & \sigma_{YZ} & \sigma_Z^2
\end{bmatrix}$$
vs
$$\epsilon_t \sim N(0, \sigma_Z^2)$$
$$\epsilon_{1t} \sim N(0, \sigma_X^2)$$
$$\epsilon_{2t} \sim N(0, \sigma_Y^2)$$
Can someone please help me understand this??

The main issue is that your model is nor V-AR neither V-ARMA. You can see that your first equation is ARMA(1,1) as it includes one AR term $Z_{t-1}$ and one MA term $\epsilon_{t-1}$, while there is no MA term in the second and third equations, as they include only white noises $\epsilon_{1t}$ and $\epsilon_{2t}$.) See here [1] for a comparison of AR, MA, and ARMA models, and here [2, 3] for more details on V-ARMA models.
