Help expanding matrix equations in vector autoregression
Yesterday I posted this question:Difficulty understanding matrix notation where I set up 3 models:
$$Z_t = \phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$$
$$X_t = \alpha_1 X_{t-1} + \beta_1 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_1 Z_{t-1} + \epsilon_{1t}$$
$$Y_t = \alpha_2 X_{t-1} + \beta_2 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_2 Z_{t-1} + \epsilon_{2t}$$
Where:

Z only depends on previous values of Z
X depends on previous values of Z, X, Y
Y depends on previous values of Z, X, Y

Goal: I wanted to make an extension of this model as follows: $Y_t$ and $X_t$ depend on the forecasted value of $Z_t$ as well as $Z_{t-1}$ .
I am wondering how to write this model.
Initially, I thought it could be simply written as follows:
$$Z_t = \phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$$
$$X_t = \alpha_1 X_{t-1} + \beta_1 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_1 Z_{t-1} + \gamma_3 Z_{t}  + \epsilon_{1t}$$
$$Y_t = \alpha_2 X_{t-1} + \beta_2 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_2 Z_{t-1} 
 + \gamma_4 Z_{t} + \epsilon_{2t}$$
But I was told that this is an incorrect way to write the model (why?). I tried to ask for clarifications, and I was given a hint to try expanding the equations.
Here is my attempt:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & -\gamma_3 \\
0 & 1 & -\gamma_4 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
X_t \\
Y_t \\
Z_t
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 X_{t-1} + \beta_1 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_1 Z_{t-1} + \gamma_3\theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_{1t} \\
\alpha_2 X_{t-1} + \beta_2 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_2 Z_{t-1} + \gamma_4\theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_{2t} \\
\phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
X_t \\
Y_t \\
Z_t
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & \gamma_3 \\
0 & 1 & \gamma_4 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 X_{t-1} + \beta_1 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_1 Z_{t-1} + \gamma_3\theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_{1t} \\
\alpha_2 X_{t-1} + \beta_2 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_2 Z_{t-1} + \gamma_4\theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_{2t} \\
\phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t
\end{pmatrix}$$
I started looking at $X_t$. From the matrix multiplication, we get:
$$X_t = (\alpha_1 X_{t-1} + \beta_1 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_1 Z_{t-1} + \gamma_3\theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_{1t}) + \gamma_3(\phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t)$$
$$X_t = \alpha_1 X_{t-1} + \beta_1 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_1 Z_{t-1} + \gamma_3\theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_{1t} + \gamma_3\phi Z_{t-1} + \gamma_3\theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \gamma_3 \epsilon_t$$

The $Z_{t-1}$ terms: $\gamma_1 Z_{t-1} + \gamma_3\phi Z_{t-1} = (\gamma_1 + \gamma_3\phi) Z_{t-1}$

The $\epsilon_{t-1}$ terms: $\gamma_3\theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \gamma_3\theta \epsilon_{t-1} = 2\gamma_3\theta \epsilon_{t-1}$


This gives us:
$$X_t = \alpha_1 X_{t-1} + \beta_1 Y_{t-1} + (\gamma_1 + \gamma_3\phi) Z_{t-1} + 2\gamma_3\theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \gamma_3 \epsilon_t + \epsilon_{1t}$$
I think this is where the problem might be. In the original equation, we only had one $\gamma_3\theta \epsilon_{t-1}$ term.
In the new equation:

The coefficient on $Z_{t-1}$ has changed from $\gamma_1$ to $(\gamma_1 + \gamma_3\phi)$.
We now have a $\gamma_3 \epsilon_t$ term, which wasn't in the original equation.
The error term is now effectively $(\gamma_3 \epsilon_t + \epsilon_{1t})$, which is correlated with $Z_t$ because $Z_t$ also depends on $\epsilon_t$.

This effectively creates an endogeneity  ( correlation between the independent variable and error in the dependent variable) problem, as the error term in the $X_t$ equation is now correlated with one of its explanatory variables ($Z_t$). The error term in this equation is now $(\gamma_3 \epsilon_t + \epsilon_{1t})$, which is correlated with $Z_t$, violating the assumptions of many standard estimation techniques.
Is my understanding correct? Is my algebra correct? And I wonder what can be done to fix this...

PS: Why correlated errors are problematic

I tried to show a small example to indicate why correlated errors are a problem in this context.
Consider a simple AR(1) model:
$$ Y_t = \beta Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t $$
where $\epsilon_t$ is supposed to be white noise. Assume that $\epsilon_t$ is actually correlated with $Y_t$.

Bias in $\hat{\beta}$:

To show the bias, we use the probability limit of $\hat{\beta}$:
Let $\{X_T\}_{T=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of random variables. The probability limit (plim) of this sequence is:
$$
\text{plim}_{T \to \infty} X_T = \theta
$$
if for every $\epsilon > 0$,
$$
\lim_{T \to \infty} P(|X_T - \theta| \geq \epsilon) = 0.
$$
$$ 
\begin{align}
plim(\hat{\beta}) &= plim\left(\frac{\sum_{t=2}^T Y_t Y_{t-1}}{\sum_{t=2}^T Y_{t-1}^2}\right) \\
&= \frac{plim(\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=2}^T Y_t Y_{t-1})}{plim(\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=2}^T Y_{t-1}^2)} \\
&= \frac{E[Y_t Y_{t-1}]}{E[Y_{t-1}^2]} \\
&= \frac{E[(\beta Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t)Y_{t-1}]}{E[Y_{t-1}^2]} \\
&= \frac{\beta E[Y_{t-1}^2] + E[\epsilon_t Y_{t-1}]}{E[Y_{t-1}^2]} \\
&= \beta + \frac{E[\epsilon_t Y_{t-1}]}{E[Y_{t-1}^2]}
\end{align}
$$
If $\epsilon_t$ is correlated with $Y_t$ (and thus with $Y_{t-1}$), then $E[\epsilon_t Y_{t-1}] \neq 0$, and $\hat{\beta}$ is biased.

Incorrect Variance Estimation:

The OLS estimate of the error variance is:
$$ \hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{T-1}\sum_{t=2}^T (Y_t - \hat{\beta}Y_{t-1})^2 $$
If we expand this:
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{\sigma}^2 &= \frac{1}{T-1}\sum_{t=2}^T ((Y_t - \beta Y_{t-1}) + (\beta - \hat{\beta})Y_{t-1})^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{T-1}\sum_{t=2}^T (\epsilon_t + (\beta - \hat{\beta})Y_{t-1})^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{T-1}\sum_{t=2}^T (\epsilon_t^2 + 2\epsilon_t(\beta - \hat{\beta})Y_{t-1} + (\beta - \hat{\beta})^2Y_{t-1}^2)
\end{align}
$$
The expected value of this estimator is:
$$
\begin{align}
E[\hat{\sigma}^2] &= E[\epsilon_t^2] + 2E[\epsilon_t(\beta - \hat{\beta})Y_{t-1}] + E[(\beta - \hat{\beta})^2Y_{t-1}^2] \\
&\neq \sigma^2
\end{align}
$$
Thus resulting in an incorrect variance.

OP here - we learned today that taking the Expected Value of $Z_t$ (i.e. forecasted value using information before $t-1$) can help solve this problem I posted about... but I am not sure why. It sounds a bit disingenuous since very little changes by doing this... but here is my attempt to expand on this idea.
Again, I tried to manually work out some of the algebra:
Here are the new equations with the replacement of the Expected Value:
$$
\begin{align}
Z_t &= \phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t \\
X_t &= \alpha_1 X_{t-1} + \beta_1 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_1 Z_{t-1} + \gamma_3 E_{t-1}[Z_t] + \epsilon_{1t} \\
Y_t &= \alpha_2 X_{t-1} + \beta_2 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_2 Z_{t-1} + \gamma_4 E_{t-1}[Z_t] + \epsilon_{2t}
\end{align}
$$
Calculate $E_{t-1}[Z_t]$:
$$
E_{t-1}[Z_t] = E_{t-1}[\phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t] = \phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1}
$$
Substitute this into our equations for $X_t$ and $Y_t$:
$$
\begin{align}
X_t &= \alpha_1 X_{t-1} + \beta_1 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_1 Z_{t-1} + \gamma_3 (\phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1}) + \epsilon_{1t} \\
Y_t &= \alpha_2 X_{t-1} + \beta_2 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_2 Z_{t-1} + \gamma_4 (\phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1}) + \epsilon_{2t}
\end{align}
$$
Expanding:
$$
\begin{align}
X_t &= \alpha_1 X_{t-1} + \beta_1 Y_{t-1} + (\gamma_1 + \gamma_3\phi) Z_{t-1} + \gamma_3\theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_{1t} \\
Y_t &= \alpha_2 X_{t-1} + \beta_2 Y_{t-1} + (\gamma_2 + \gamma_4\phi) Z_{t-1} + \gamma_4\theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_{2t} \\
Z_t &= \phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t
\end{align}
$$
$$Xt=α1Xt−1+β1Yt−1+(γ1+γ3ϕ)Zt−1+2γ3θϵt−1+γ3ϵt+ϵ1t$$
Write in matrix form:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
X_t \\
Y_t \\
Z_t
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 & \beta_1 & \gamma_1 + \gamma_3\phi \\
\alpha_2 & \beta_2 & \gamma_2 + \gamma_4\phi \\
0 & 0 & \phi
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
X_{t-1} \\
Y_{t-1} \\
Z_{t-1}
\end{pmatrix} +
\begin{pmatrix}
\gamma_3\theta & 1 & 0 \\
\gamma_4\theta & 0 & 1 \\
\theta & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\epsilon_{t-1} \\
\epsilon_{1t} \\
\epsilon_{2t}
\end{pmatrix} +
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\epsilon_t
$$
The expected value approach creates a recursive system instead of a simultaneous one:
$$ Z_t = \phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t $$
$$ X_t = \alpha_1 X_{t-1} + \beta_1 Y_{t-1} + (\gamma_1 + \gamma_3\phi) Z_{t-1} + \gamma_3\theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_{1t} $$
$$ Y_t = \alpha_2 X_{t-1} + \beta_2 Y_{t-1} + (\gamma_2 + \gamma_4\phi) Z_{t-1} + \gamma_4\theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_{2t} $$
In this new system, we have broken the simultaneity. By using $E_{t-1}[Z_t]$, we're not using the actual value of $Z_t$ (which includes $\epsilon_t$), but rather its best prediction based on past information. This breaks the contemporaneous link between the variables and solves the simultaneity problem. Supposedly this is sufficient justification for this approach - but to me it still seems very little has changed? Perhaps the distribution of $E_{t-1}[Z_t]$ is different than $Z_t$ - e.g. $E_{t-1}[Z_t]$ has larger variance, thus providing a more realistic estimate?
Some final remarks - when we compare this to the original system:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -\gamma_3 \\
0 & 1 & -\gamma_4 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
X_t \\
Y_t \\
Z_t
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 X_{t-1} + \beta_1 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_1 Z_{t-1} + \gamma_3\theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_{1t} \\
\alpha_2 X_{t-1} + \beta_2 Y_{t-1} + \gamma_2 Z_{t-1} + \gamma_4\theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_{2t} \\
\phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t
\end{pmatrix}
$$
In the new system, $X_t$ and $Y_t$ do not depend on the contemporaneous $Z_t$.
The error terms $\epsilon_{1t}$ and $\epsilon_{2t}$ are  also not correlated with any of the explanatory variables. The only equation that includes $\epsilon_t$ is the equation for $Z_t$, and it does not feed back into the equations for $X_t$ and $Y_t$.
Looking at the covariance between the error terms and $Z_t$:
For $X_t$: $Cov(\epsilon_{1t}, Z_t) = Cov(\epsilon_{1t}, \phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t) = 0$
For $Y_t$: $Cov(\epsilon_{2t}, Z_t) = Cov(\epsilon_{2t}, \phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t) = 0$
In contrast, in the original system:
$$ Cov(\epsilon_{1t}, Z_t) = Cov(\epsilon_{1t}, \phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t) = Cov(\epsilon_{1t}, \epsilon_t) \neq 0 $$
$$ Cov(\epsilon_{2t}, Z_t) = Cov(\epsilon_{2t}, \phi Z_{t-1} + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t) = Cov(\epsilon_{2t}, \epsilon_t) \neq 0 $$
In the new approach, the covariances are zero because $\epsilon_{1t}$ and $\epsilon_{2t}$ are assumed to be uncorrelated with $Z_{t-1}$, $\epsilon_{t-1}$, and $\epsilon_t$. In the original system, $Z_t$ included $\epsilon_t$, which created the simultaneity problem. Now, $E_{t-1}[Z_t]$ does not include $\epsilon_t$.
Apparently doing this expected value approach is sufficient to fix the simultaneity problem by ensuring that all explanatory variables in each equation are predetermined, breaking the contemporaneous link between $X_t$, $Y_t$, and $Z_t$, and eliminating the correlation between the error terms and the explanatory variables.
PS: We can apparently show (I haven't verified this yet) that unlike the original case, the estimators maintain desirable statistical properties under the new approach:
$$ plim(\hat{\alpha_1}) = \alpha_1 $$
$$ plim(\hat{\beta_1}) = \beta_1 $$
$$ plim(\hat{\gamma_1}) = \gamma_1 $$
